# If a Pandas column doesn't contain a value from another column in the same row, then add the value from another column in a new line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, contains

I want to add values from column "A" to column "B" in a new line, only if the corresponding value from column "A" is not contained in column "B".

My data frame:

```
df

  A          B
  value1     value4
  value1
  value1     value4\nvalue1\n
  value2     value4\nvalue7\n
  value2     value4\n
  value3
  value3     value4\nvalue3\nvalue6
  value3     value2\nvalue1
  value3     value3\nvalue1\nvalue6
```

So, my desired data frame

```
df

  A          B
  value1     value4\nvalue1
  value1     value1
  value1     value4\nvalue1
  value2     value4\nvalue7\nvalue2
  value2     value4\nvalue2
  value3     value3
  value3     value4\nvalue3\nvalue6
  value3     value2\nvalue1\nvalue3
  value3     value3\nvalue1\nvalue6
```

Additionally, the problem is that sometimes at the end of the string in column "B", a \n is present and sometimes is not.

I tried with `df.A.str.contains(df["A"])`, but it doesn't work when `contains()` has a data frame column. I think that something like this could work: `df.B.str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(df.A))`, and this is only for the values from column "A" which are present in column "B" - for matches, and I don't know how to adapt to my problem.

Comment: This is a messy question. To better help you, we will need to see the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Boolean mask with a list comprehension. Replace missing values with the empty string and use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
mask = [a in b for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'].fillna(''))]
b = df['B'].str.replace(r'\\n$', '')
df['B'] = b.where(mask, b + '\\n' + df['A']).fillna(df['A'])
print (df)
        A                       B
0  value1          value4\nvalue1
1  value1                  value1
2  value1          value4\nvalue1
3  value2  value4\nvalue7\nvalue2
4  value2          value4\nvalue2
5  value3                  value3
6  value3  value4\nvalue3\nvalue6
7  value3  value2\nvalue1\nvalue3
8  value3  value3\nvalue1\nvalue6
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But there is the problem with adding to a string which already contains \n at the end, then I have one empty line and I don't want that. Also, in the third row in column "B" there is \n at the end and I do not want that.

Comment: @jezrael-to summarized - I don't need \n\n (two new lines), i only need  \n (one new line), and without \n at the end of string. Everything else is as it should be.

Comment: @slobokv83 - ya, here is not possible use `strip`, because it repalce also `n`, so need [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `$` for match last value. check edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael-it works perfectly, thank you very much...but I wonder, why I always have to write "\n" instead of yours "\\n"? Then it works, if I change both "\\n" that you wrote to "\n".

Comment: @slobokv83 - I think I use windows, so need escape `'\'` by `'\\'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `df.apply` for that purpose. Inside you will be able to use `lambda` to create your condition. As well, I use `strip()` to remove the `\n` from the beginning and the end. See the code below:

```
# Code to build the dataframe
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': ['value1', 'value1', 'value1', 'value2', 'value2', 'value3', 'value3', 'value3', 'value3'], 'B': ['value4', '', 'value4\nvalue1\n', 'value4\nvalue7\n', 'value4\n', '', 'value4\nvalue3\nvalue6', 'value2\nvalue1', 'value3\nvalue1\nvalue6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Here is the code to use
print(df.apply(lambda x: [x["A"], (x["B"].strip()+"\n"+x["A"]).strip()] if x["A"] not in x["B"] else [x["A"], x["B"].strip()], axis=1, result_type='broadcast'))
```

Output:

```
        A                         B
0  value1            value4\nvalue1
1  value1                    value1
2  value1            value4\nvalue1
3  value2    value4\nvalue7\nvalue2
4  value2            value4\nvalue2
5  value3                    value3
6  value3    value4\nvalue3\nvalue6
7  value3    value2\nvalue1\nvalue3
8  value3    value3\nvalue1\nvalue6
8  value3    value3\nvalue1\nvalue6
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have to learn and often use if statement in lambda function, but I am in the learning process in pandas.

Comment: Aha, thank you for that, because I have more than 30 000 lines for this that I asked. I have to switch because I have fillna(), replace()...

Comment: @JonathanGagne - No, you are wrong. Apply are loops under th hood, so slowier. I check it - `df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)` for 9000 rows.

Comment: @JonathanGagne - and get `mask = [a in b for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'].fillna(''))]
b = df['B'].str.replace(r'\\n$', '')
df['B'] = b.where(mask, b + '\\n' + df['A']).fillna(df['A'])

13.2 ms ± 724 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
(df.apply(lambda x: [x["A"], (x["B"].strip()+"\n"+x["A"]).strip()] if x["A"] not in x["B"] else [x["A"], x["B"].strip()], axis=1, result_type='broadcast'))


651 ms ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @JonathanGagne - sure, please for e.g. 10000 rows

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, your solution is solid. Boolean mask with comprehension list, I love it!